# Name a case expression?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a case expression in a DB2 statement like the following.

```
SELECT A,
   CASE WHEN B LIKE ' %'
      THEN C
      ELSE B
   END CASE,
   D
FROM TAB
```

I'd like to name the column that the case expression results in, but I get a syntax error with both the `AS` immediately following `END CASE` and by wrapping the entire expression in parentheses and following that with an `AS`.

Adding the AS (without the parens) results in the following error

> 199:  SQL0199N  The use of the reserved word "AS" following "" is not valid.  Expected tokens may include:  ", FROM INTO".  SQLSTATE=42601

How can I name this column?

Comment: Are you sure you should be using `END CASE`? A quick google ***suggests*** to me that this is for procedure control *(like IF statements, etc)*, not for use inside a SELECT statement. Have you tried just using `END` instead? *[Also, it helps if you include the error message, sometimes it can prove useful.]*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ending keyword is not `END CASE`, it's just `END`:

```
SELECT A,
   CASE WHEN B LIKE ' %'
      THEN C
      ELSE B
   END AS D                 --- the AS is optional
FROM TAB
```

Here's the [documentation for CASE expression](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref%2Fcaseexp.htm) in DB2 - although it's not needed really, that's standard SQL.